# Concatenate multiple file rowwise in a single dataframe with the same header name

Tags: dataframe, concatenation

I have 400 csv files and all the files contains single column which has 4667 rows . Every row has name and corresponding value for example "A=54,B=56 and so on till 4667 rows. My problem statement is :
1. fetch the variable name and put it different columns
2. fetch the corresponding variable value and put it in the next rows above the columns.

[image]
3. Now, Do this step for all the 400 files and append all the corresponding values in the above rows which makes 400 rows.
[image]

I have done for the single file and how to do with the multiple files . I don't Know

```
import glob
from collections import OrderedDict

path =r'Github/dataset/Raw_Dataset/'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dict_of_df = OrderedDict((f, pd.read_csv((f),header=None,names=['Devices'])) for f in filenames)
eda=pd.concat(dict_of_df)
```

I

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a concatenation?
you could use pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C","D"],data=[["1","2","3","4"]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C","D"],data=[["5","6","7","8"]])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C","D"],data=[["9","10","11","12"]])

df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

print(df_concat)
```

In combination with a loop through the files in the folder ending with ".csv" it would be:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = r"C:\YOUR\DICTIONARY"

df_concat = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"): 
        print(filename)
        df_temp = pd.read_csv(path + "\\" + filename)
        df_concat = pd.concat([df_concat, df_temp])
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: using concatenation all the values in single column. But I want all the variable names such as A, B, C of single file in one row and their corresponding value in another row and similarly concatinate just the values of the variable in different rows instead of columns.

Comment: @anmol, The code should do exactly do that. Have your csv files by chance another delimiter than ","? If yes you need to set it like this pd.read_csv(delimiter=";"). Otherwise, could you make a screenshot or an example of two files and one of the desired output of those two files?